# How does "would" fuction in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, modal-verbs

Could you explain how "would" works in the following sentence? Speaker asks a question, then speaker B uses "would" when replying to the question. I'd really like to understand its use.

> A: Which questions are more natural to express the period of time 'an hour and a half' in the answer? I am with all of them.

> 1. How long will you spend at the gym?
> 2. How much time will you spend at the gym?
>    I will spend an hour and a half.
>    Is it 'for' optional in the answer?
> 3. How long will you be at the gym?
>    I'll be there (for) an hour and a half

> ​B: To me, the most natural is #3. Another natural question **would be**: 'How long are you going to be at the gym?'
> And the most natural answer, in my opinion, **would be** simply, 'An hour and a half'.

Answer (score 3):

**Would** can be used when suggesting a possibility. B suggests a way of asking the question that they think is as natural as the three alternatives given by A. It's a form of the conditional tense - "If you were to say it that way, it *would* sound natural."

Comment: Thanks. What is the difference between a sentence that uses "would" and one that with not "would?" I've quite often seen native speakers say that. For example: **I would interpret that as...** / **I interpret that as..., I would take it to mean as...** / **I take it to mean as...**

Comment: Using the conditional tense makes the statement a little more 'tentative' and therefore more polite - the speaker is suggesting an interpretation rather than stating that their interpretation is the right one.

Comment: But there is no conditional in those sentences. The speaker only uses "would."

Comment: Well, it's a sort of implied conditional - "[If you were to ask me] I would say that..."

Comment: Well, that doesn't quite make sense, because the speaker does ask a question.

Comment: You mean it's a _reply_ to a question? Whether or not it's strictly the conditional, it's a fact that we use expressions like _I would like, I would suggest_ to sound more polite than _I want, I think you should_.

Comment: Yes, it's a reply to a question. So the implied condition (if you were to ask me) doesn't make sense because the questioner does ask a question.

Comment: Then the implied condition is something like, "*If I were to try and answer, ...*". Either way, it's an implied conditional, and the only real function is to be more polite by being indirect.