# What is the difference between the form with "would" and with no "would?"

Tags: word-usage, modal-verbs

I want to understand the use of "would" in this sentence.This is a reply to a question. Here, B uses "would" when answering the question. Could you explain how "would" works here? I usually just say "I call that..." with no "would."

> **A**: *if you are tired, you should go to bed.*
> Is this the first conditional or zero conditional for you?

> **B**: I **would** call that a zero conditional.
> Conditionals along the lines of 'If it rains, we'll cancel the match' are generally categorised as first conditionals.

Comment: Why have you included a question mark after *you should go to bed*. Are you simply asking whether it makes any difference whether speaker B includes the optional auxiliary verb ***would***? It doesn't, really - just adds a slight nuance of hesitancy / uncertainty (or perhaps "polite deference"). Is any of your text about "conditionals" relevant to the question?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sorry, it was a typo. Could you explain?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I meant why does speaker B use "would?" If just saying "I call that..", what is the difference?

Comment: How is this different from [your own question from yesterday](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/337136/how-does-would-fuction-in-this-sentence)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does "would" fuction in this sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/337136/how-does-would-fuction-in-this-sentence)

Answer (score 1):

The implied hypothetical is "if I encountered such a phrase" or "if I were considering such a phrase".

The reason for the irrealis even when said condition is factual is that it suggests restraint (as FumbleFingers said) and that can indicate uncertainty or simple politeness.

Practically speaking, "I call that a zero conditional" sounds somewhat too authoritative and final, as though you were the one who decided what the thing is called or were at least teaching us what the thing is called. (Which is true in this example, but it's impolite to draw attention to it.)

> — Look at that cute dog!
> — Dog? I call that a mutt.

Tone: definitive, disdainful, contrary.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense. "Would" here shows a certainty on the speaker. It's as if there is an implied condition and makes the statement sound less direct. "I would call that.../I call that...", in both of these sentences the basic meaning is the same. Adding in the word "would" makes the claim sounds less direct and a bit more hypothetical. Is my understanding right?

Comment: I explained all this to you yesterday in response to your earlier question!